# How to Work with Twitter API

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

i want the json of the national geographic channel and i'm creating a template with jquery and making live feeds of twitter on my web page.

This is the page from which i want the JSON

https://twitter.com/NatGeo

and i'm using https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search.json?q=NatGeo to search for a JSON Code but it says

```
  {"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}
```

Comment: It seems the API endpoint for searching needs to be : `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=NatGeo` and additional credentials for authentication need to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

Please if you have time, focus on pairs of sets of name / value ;
ordered lists of values from the Twitter @Natgeo.

Gwenaëlle Sachet